# Can mypy detect bad TypedDict return types?

Tags: pycharm, static-analysis, mypy, python-3.8

I'm trying to get mypy to work comprehensively enough for my project.

```
from typing import TypedDict

OurDict = TypedDict('OurDict', {'x': int})

bad: OurDict = {'y': 2}  # mypy successfully marks wrong
good: OurDict = {'x': 2}  # mypy likes this


def get_bad() -> OurDict:
    return 234  # mypy successfully marks wrong


def get_good() -> OurDict:
    res = {'x': 2}
    return res  # mypy successfully marks correct


def get_should_be_bad() -> OurDict:
    return {'hello': 2, 'world': 1}  # mypy fails to see a problem
```

It seems like mypy can detect whether a dictionary conforms to a type definition when it is declared inline but when checking function return values it only checks that the return value is some kind of dictionary, rather than being the desired type.  Is that just a limit in the design or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: With Python 3.8 and `mypy==0.761`, I get `error: Extra keys ('hello', 'world') for TypedDict "OurDict"` in `get_should_be_bad`'s body.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out that it was a versioning issue.  I was running mypy inside of the python 3.8 venv which I assumed would use the mypy inside the venv but it turned out it was using the system mypy. When I typed python -m mypy it worked correctly.  Should I delete this post?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out mypy has no problem detecting this, but I mistakenly thought typing invoking mypy from within the venv would use they mypy inside the venv.  I had to type python3 -m mypy to get the correct executable to run.